# MySQL - MEMORY storage engine in multithread app

Tags: mysql, multithreading

Is it safe to use MEMORY storage engine in multithreaded application ? I have one writer and many readers. Is it possible to read incomplete data when INSERT is executing in writer thread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory engine performs table lock at the time of the update , so you shouldn't be able to read partial data.

Check this out:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html